# jQuery finding out what is at a particular X/Y co-ordinate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey, I have the following function:

```
function getPosition() {
    var cLeft = $('#element').position().left;
    var cTop = $('#element').position().top;
}
```

I also have this:

```
$('ul#container>li.node:eq('+XXX+')').css({'border' : '5px solid yellow'});
```

Now, is it possible to determine what index for the LI's is at the co-ordinates provided by `getPosition()` ?

*Note: **XXX** denotes where I would like the index of the LI's to be.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some plain JavaScript

```
var elementAtCoords = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

I'm not sure support for IE, but [Firefox has had it since 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint).

To start going crazy with jQuery, simply wrap it

```
$(elementAtCoords).slideDown(2000);
```

Comment: ***mock cockney accent*** Nice one my son!